# What causes VueJS to stop updating the DOM in this instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I've looked on every similar post that I can find, but no answer seems to fix my issue. Specifically, it does not update the table with id "table".

HTML:

```
<section id="body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading" id="panel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Filters</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <form id="filterForm" class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Category:</label>
                                            <select id="category" class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
                                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                                <option v-for="category in categories" value="category.categoryTitle">
                                                {{category.categoryTitle}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="control-label" style="margin-right:20px;">Air Date:</label>
                                            <div style="width:35%" class="form-group">
                                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" v-model="airDate"/>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="control-label">Show Number:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="number" id="showNumber" v-model="showNumber">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="control-label">Question contains:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="text" v-model="questionText">
                                            <label class="control-label">Dollar Value:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="number" id="showNumber" v-model="dollarValue">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-3" style="margin-top:5px;">                                   
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="reset">Reset Filters</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="filter">Filter</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="tableCard" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:40px;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Jeopardy Questions</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <span id="totalQuestionsSpan">Total Entries: {{entries.length}} entries</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:45px;">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <table id="tableScroll" class="table table-striped table-fixed">
                                <thead style="background-color:white;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 110px;">
                                            Question
                                            <span v-if="questionSort == 1" id="questionUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="questionDown == -1" id="questionDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 120px; ">
                                            Answer
                                            <span v-if="answerSort == 1" id="answerUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="answerDown == -1" id="answerDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Value
                                            <span v-if="valueSort == 1" id="valueUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="valueDown == -1" id="valueDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Show Number
                                            <span v-if="showNumberSort == 1" id="showNumberUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="showNumberDown == -1" id="showNumberDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Category
                                            <span v-if="categorySort == 1" id="categoryUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="categoryDown == -1" id="categoryDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Air Date
                                            <span v-if="airDateSort == 1" id="airDateUp">&#9650;</span>
                                            <span v-else-if="airDateDown == -1" id="airDateDown">&#9660;</span>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="table">
                                    <tr v-for="entry in entries">
                                        <td>{{entry.questionText}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.answerText}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.dollarValue}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.showNumber}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.categoryTitle}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.airDate}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr v-if="entries.length == 0">
                                        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center;"> No entries to display </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#body',
        data: {
            loggedIn: false,
            questionSort: 0,
            answerSort: 0,
            valueSort: 0,
            showNumberSort: 0,
            categorySort: 0,
            airDateSort: 0,
            entries: [],
            url: "/questions",
            categories: [],

            // form model data
            categoryTitle: '',
            airDate: '',
            questionText: '',
            dollarValue: '',
            showNumber: '',
        },
        mounted: function () {
            $.get("/api/categories", function(result) {
               Vue.set(app, "categories", result.data);
                $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
            }, "json").fail(function(err) {
                showErrorMessage(err.responseJSON.message_prettified);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            filter : function() {
                var queryParams = "?";
                var params = 0;
                app.categoryTitle = $('#category :selected').text().trim();
                if (typeof app.categoryTitle !== "undefined" && app.categoryTitle != null) {
                    params++;
                    queryParams += "categoryTitle=" + app.categoryTitle
                }
                if (app.airDate.length > 0) {
                    params++;
                    if (params > 0) {
                        queryParams += "&";
                    }
                    queryParams += "airDate=" + app.airDate
                }
                if (app.questionText.length > 0) {
                    params++;
                    if (params > 0) {
                        queryParams += "&";
                    }
                    queryParams += "questionText=" + app.questionText
                }
                if (app.dollarValue.length > 0) {
                    params++;
                    if (params > 0) {
                        queryParams += "&";
                    }
                    queryParams += "dollarValue=" + app.dollarValue
                }
                if (app.showNumber.length > 0) {
                    params++;
                    if (params > 0) {
                        queryParams += "&";
                    }
                    queryParams += "showNumber=" + app.showNumber
                }
                if (queryParams.length == 1) {
                    queryParams = "";
                }
                var url = "/questions"
                var URL = url + queryParams;
                $.get(URL, result => {   
                        Vue.set(app, "entries", result.data);
                        app.$forceUpdate();
                    }, "json").fail(function(err) {
                        showErrorMessage(err.responseJSON.message_prettified);
                    }).always(function() {
                       $("#loader").addClass("toggled");
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Current behavior:

The AJAX call to /api/categories correctly updates the dropdown on the DOM, allowing me to select a category. When the app is mounted, it does update the table, showing the colspan 6 "No entries to display" cell. However, after the filter request is sent and returns, the table does not update to reflect the updated data (despite the data correctly showing as having been changed when checked in the console).

Expected behavior:

When the AJAX call to /questions with the query params resolves and updates the entries data field in app, the table updates to reflect the changes.

Attempted fixes:

Explored $forceUpdate, $set, Vue.set, and manually overwriting the array using a for loop.

**Edit:**

After doing a lot of snooping and also integrating VueX (as suggested below by @WaldemarIce) which may have helped but regardless did improve the overall code structure of my mini program, I've arrived to a solution.

This post on Laracast made me wonder whether perhaps there was a data issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/v-for-loop-rendering-keeps-throwing-undefined-error

Which then caused me to realize the problem was in this line of code here:

```
<option v-for="category in categories" value="category.categoryTitle">
                                            {{category.categoryTitle}}</option>
```

Which was causing an issue because category in value="category.categoryTitle" wasn't defined until later in the life cycle. I changed that to v-bind:value="category.categoryTitle" and updated my JS to make it work now. The TypeError that I posted in the follow-up discussions on @Kaicui 's post was causing Vue to lose the reactivity of the data. Once I solved that problem, Vue began to react properly again.

Updated HTML:

```
<section id="body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading" id="panel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Filters</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                <i id="toggleFilter" class="fa fa-chevron-down filter-collapsed" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <i id="toggleFilter" class="fa fa-chevron-up filter-collapsed"  aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <form id="filterForm" method="GET" action="/questions" class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="categoryTitle" id="categoryTitleHidden">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Category:</label>
                                            <select style="width:90%; height:120% !important;" v-model="categorySelect" id="category" class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
                                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                                <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="category.categoryTitle">
                                                {{category.categoryTitle}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                                            <label class="control-label" style="margin-right:20px;">Air Date:</label>
                                            <div style="width:35%; margin-right:10px" class="form-group">
                                                <div style="width:100%" class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="airDate"/>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="control-label">Show Number:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="number" id="showNumber" name="showNumber">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="control-label">Question contains:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="text" id="questionText" name="questionText">
                                            <label class="control-label">Dollar Value:</label>
                                            <input style="width:35%" class="form-control" type="number" id="dollarValue" name="dollarValue">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-3" style="margin-top:5px;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="reset">Reset Filters</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="filter">Filter</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="tableCard" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:40px;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Jeopardy Questions</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <span id="totalQuestionsSpan">Total Entries: {{entryCount}} entries</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:45px;">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <table id="tableScroll" class="table table-striped table-fixed">
                                <thead style="background-color:white;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 110px;">
                                            Question
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 120px; ">
                                            Answer
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Value
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Show Number
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Category
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="cursor:pointer; min-width: 80px;">
                                            Air Date
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="table">
                                    <tr v-if="entriesValid" v-for="entry in entries">
                                        <td>{{entry.questionText}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.answerText}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.dollarValue}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.showNumber}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.categoryTitle}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.airDate}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr v-if="!entriesValid">
                                        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center;"> No entries to display </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 45%; top:25%; z-index:3;">
        <i id="loader" class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw toggled" style="z-index:3"></i>
    </div>
</section>
```

Updated JS

```
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    Vue.config.debug = false;
    Vue.config.silent = true;
    var URL;
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            loggedIn: false,

            // ordering data
            questionSort: 0,
            answerSort: 0,
            valueSort: 0,
            showNumberSort: 0,
            categorySort: 0,
            airDateSort: 0,

            // server related ata
            entries: [],
            url: "/questions",
            categories: [{
                categoryTitle: "Test",
            }],
        },
        mutations: {
            categories (state, data) {
                state.categories = data;
            },
            entries (state, data) {
                console.log(data);
                state.entries = data;
                console.log(state.entries)
            }
        },
        actions: {
            fetchCategories ({ commit }) {
                $("#loader").removeClass("toggled");
                $.get("/api/categories", function(result) {
                    commit('categories', result.data);
                }, "json")
                .fail(function(err) {
                    if (err.status == 0) {
                        showErrorMessage("Network Problem");
                    }
                    else {
                        showErrorMessage(err.responseJSON.message_prettified);
                    }
                }).always(function() {
                    $("#loader").addClass("toggled");
                });
            },
        },
    });

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#body',
        store: store,
        data: {
            categorySelect: "",
        },
        mounted: function() {
            store.dispatch("fetchCategories").then(() => {
                $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
            });
        },
        computed: {
            categories: function() {
                return store.state.categories;
            },
            entryCount: function() {
                if (store.entries) {
                    if (typeof store.entries.length !== "undefined") {
                        return store.entries.length;
                    }
                    else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            },
            entriesValid: function() {
                if (store.state.entries) {
                    if (typeof store.state.entries.length !== "undefined" && store.state.entries.length > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            entries: function() {
                return store.state.entries;
            },
            loggedIn: function() {
                return store.state.loggedIn;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            reset: function() {
                $('.js-example-basic-single').val('').trigger('change');
                $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("clear");
                $("#categoryTitleHidden").val("");
                $("#showNumber").val("");
                $("#questionText").val("");
                $("#showNumber").val("");
                $("#dollarValue").val("");
            },
            filter : function() {
                var value = $('#category :selected').text().trim();
                if (value !== "Any") {
                    $("#categoryTitleHidden").val(value);
                }
                else {
                    $("#categoryTitleHidden").val("");   
                }
                var options = {   
                    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                        store.commit("entries", JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data)
                    } 
                }; 
                $("#filterForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO problem is causing Vue.set(app, ...). AFAIK you can't set properties on Vue instance itself.

**EDIT**: Live example with Vuex and async data with jQuery

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // Car manufacturers for datalist will be held here.
    // Cars are globally accessible, in every component,
    // as this.$store.state.cars
    cars: null
  },
  mutations: {
    // Mutations changes state, but must be sync,
    // so you can't call $.get() or another 
    // async function in any mutation.
    updateCars: function (state, payload) {
      state.cars = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    // For async ops there are actions,
    // but they can't change state - for state
    // change fire particular mutation.
    loadCars: function (context, payload) {
      $.get(payload.src).then(function (data) {
        context.commit('updateCars', data)
      })
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('my-list', {
  template: '#my-list',
  props: ['src'],
  // All components see this.$store.state.cars, but
  // still can have own local data.
  data: function () {
    return {
      manufacturer: ''
    }
  },
  // Fire async store action
  created: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch({
      type: 'loadCars',
      src: this.src
    })
  }
  // Alternatively, you can use this
  // version - w/o action. It's OK to use
  // mutation here, in callback of async function.
  /* created: function () {
    $.get(this.src).then(function (data) {
      this.$store.commit('updateCars', data)
    })
  } */
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // Inject store state to all components
  store: store
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-list src="https://api.mockaroo.com/api/32318a80?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0">
  </my-list>
</div>

<template id="my-list">
  <div>
    <label>
      Choose a car manufacturer:<br>
      <input list="cars" name="myCars" v-model="manufacturer">
    </label>
    <datalist id="cars">
      <option
        v-for="car in $store.state.cars"
        :value="car.car"
      >
        {{ car.id }}
      </option>
    </datalist>
    <p>
      Selected manufacturer:<br>
      {{ manufacturer }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.0/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried doing direct assignment (app.entries = result.data) but that didn't work either. I had done some reading that the Vue.set function might trigger a forced update of the DOM (didn't work). 

What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Its because you can't set properties on root data object of a Vue instance also... Use Vuex, it's best thing you can do.

Comment: I'll give Vuex a shot and see if that fixes the problem. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check in once I've given it a shot.

Comment: If you want, I can write an example here. Basic Vuex usage with async data.

Comment: Hi WaldemarIce. Thanks for all the help. After a great deal of frustration I did get it to work, and just for the sake of anyone who sees this later I'll post my findings in the original post. The problem ended up being a mixture of issues between incorrectly referencing data that already existed in the root scope, and loading the data from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

your code can not run because it relies on your server response.

but i think your code which setting resonse data to `entries` is fine.

This kind of problems may occur when other js code have caused an exception ,which interrupt the rendering of vue.

so could you check console and see is there any errors?

Comment: The server response is essentially just an array of JSON objects, Ill post an image of the console that shows what the app has after the AJAX resolves

Post AJAX content of entries:
https://imgur.com/a/Qcuby


Example of JSON schema
https://imgur.com/a/V9F91

Comment: There is a VueJS error, however based on what I could google, that had to do with a referencing of data before it is loaded, and resolves itself once it has been loaded. I'll provide a photo of the error here. https://imgur.com/a/OEVuF