# How to display this using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

```
{ message: "Hello how are you", status: false, state: Kerala }
```

The following values are the response of an AJAX request. Each time the response changes. I need to print it using Vue.js?

```
<script>
regBox = new Vue({
    el: "#regBox",
    data: {
        username : '',
    },
    methods: {
        handelSubmit: function(e) {
            data = {};
            data['username'] = this.username;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/user/box/',
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(e) {
                    if (e.status) {
                        alert(" Success")
                    } else {
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe the commented demo in this question will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927074/what-causes-vuejs-to-stop-updating-the-dom-in-this-instance

Comment: i did not get the idea for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example #1: just one response at a time**

```
regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
data: {
    username : '',
    response: {
        message: '',
        status: '',
        state: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
        var vm = this; // so you can access "this" inside jquery success
        data = {};
        data['username'] = this.username;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/user/box/',
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(e) {
                vm.response = e;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
},
});
```

example template:

```
<div id="regBox">
   <div v-if="response.message" class="{ 'alert-success': response.status, 'alert-danger': !response.status}">
       <p>{{ response.message }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example #2: multiple responses at a time**:

```
regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
data: {
    username : '',
    responses: []
},
methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
        data = {};
        data['username'] = this.username;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/user/box/',
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(e) {

                // like this to prevent all items to be binded, they would otherwise change whenever you get a new response.
                vm.responses.push({
                   message: e.message,
                   status: e.status,
                   state: e.state
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
},
});
```

example template:

```
<div id="regBox">
   <div class="{ 'alert-success': response.status, 'alert-danger': !response.status}" v-for="response in responses">
       <p>{{ response.message }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

afterwards, you can also use setTimeout if you want to remove the response after some time.

Comment: Also how to display it in the front end?

Comment: Hey @Wanderer i updated my answer with templates, this is just an example. If you don't know how to display data at all in vueJs, i'd suggest you do some tutorials first. (https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

I see from the `$.ajax` that you are mixing vue.js with jquery, which should be avoided whenever possible. You can use a different library for your AJAX request, such as axios.

Here is an explanation for using axios with vue.js:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/